# How to add a button in google api over the map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, dom

I want to add a button over the google map, at a certain position e.g. at latitude: 62.323907 and longitude:-150.109291. I am able to add the button but I cannot click it. Is there a way to add button over the map that can be clicked?

In the CustomImageOverlay.prototype.onAdd() I am creating the div here and the button here. I provide the style.cursor = "pointer" for div and button. However, the button is displayed on the map with the correct location but it cannot be clicked. The cursor also remains as draggable one and it only allows me to drag and not click.

Here is my code:

```js
var map;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', GoogleMap);
var chicago = { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 };

CustomImageOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function GoogleMap() 
{
  var pos =   { lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291}
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    center: pos,
    zoom: 8
  });

  overlay = new CustomImageOverlay(map, pos);

}


function CustomImageOverlay(map, position) 
{
  this.map_ = map;
  this.position_ = position;

  this.div_ = null;

  this.setMap(map);
}

CustomImageOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.cursor = "pointer";


  // Create Button
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Click Here!";
  button.style.position = 'absolute';
  button.style.cursor = "pointer";
  div.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  });


  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};


CustomImageOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  var div = this.div_;
  
  var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.position_);
  var posToPix = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(userLatLng);

   div.style.left = posToPix.x + 'px';
   div.style.top = posToPix.y + 'px';

   div.style.width = '100px';
   div.style.height = '100px';
};
```

```css
#googleMap {
    height: 100%;
  }

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="map.css">
    </head>

<body>

    <div id="googleMap"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
    <script src="map.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added google's test key to the code snippet so it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements on the `overlayLayer` pane don't receive DOM events (like `click`), append your button to the `overlayMouseTarget` pane instead.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapPanes)

> **overlayLayer**
> Type:  Element
> This pane contains polylines, polygons, ground overlays and tile layer overlays. **It does not receive DOM events. (Pane 1).**

Change:

```
panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
```

To:

```
panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', GoogleMap);
var chicago = { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 };

CustomImageOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function GoogleMap() 
{
  var pos =   { lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291}
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    center: pos,
    zoom: 8
  });

  overlay = new CustomImageOverlay(map, pos);

}


function CustomImageOverlay(map, position) 
{
  this.map_ = map;
  this.position_ = position;

  this.div_ = null;

  this.setMap(map);
}

CustomImageOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.cursor = "pointer";


  // Create Button
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Click Here!";
  button.style.position = 'absolute';
  button.style.cursor = "pointer";
  div.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("click");
    map.setCenter(chicago);
  });


  this.div_ = div;

  // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);
};


CustomImageOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  var div = this.div_;
  
  var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.position_);
  var posToPix = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(userLatLng);

   div.style.left = posToPix.x + 'px';
   div.style.top = posToPix.y + 'px';

   div.style.width = '100px';
   div.style.height = '100px';
};
```

```css
#googleMap {
    height: 100%;
  }

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>

    <div id="googleMap"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>

</body>
</html>
```